# Is this ladybird larva secreting a protective fluid?

Tags: entomology

I know that adult ladybird beetles can secrete a fluid to keep predators from eating them. Can the larvae do that too? Or are these yellow droplets something else?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology Beta!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In larvae stage Ladybird beetles secretes yellow gooey alkaloids from its abdomen.**

Ladybird beetles oozes hemolymph(in other word its blood), which is toxic and very smelly, when threatened. It's a mixture of various alkaloids and repulse the predators.

Good Job, There might be no picture more clearer than you provided

[image]

source:

[1]: [Ladybird defence alkaloids: Structural, chemotaxonomic and biosynthetic aspects (Col.: Coccinellidae), Désiré Daloze, Jean-Claude Braekman, Jacques M. Pasteels](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01240602)

[2]: [10 Fascinating Facts About Ladybugs](http://insects.about.com/od/beetles/a/10-facts-ladybugs.htm)